# Custom styling of Filters in react-table

Tags: css, react-select, react-table

I've built a table with react-table and want to use the react-select component as as filtering component. All is up and running except that the dropdown from the react-select component gets hidden by the table.

I've been working quite a long time on this issue. With styling the react-select to look nice within the filter row.

The issue is that I cannot find any other way to override the CSS rules for

```
.ReactTable .rt-th,.ReactTable .rt-td
```

which appears to control the row with all filter. This css has the rule of `overflow:hidden;` and changing it to `overflow:visible;` resolves my issue.

Hardcoding the changes in this file is of course not the "right way to do it" since I might get trouble elsewhere.

Things I've tried:

1. Passing `styles={{overflow:visible}}` to my filterComponent. This results in a strange style='Object object' and my style is not read.
2. Passing `getProps:()=>{style:{overflow:'visible'}}`. Have tried some other methods then getProps but with no luck.

Any other ideas or suggestions?

## Solution

The prop `getTheadFilterThProps` was missing in the documentation. The property was found by searching within the react-table folder and check if there where any props that were missing in the documentation.

```
<ReactTable 
    getTheadFilterThProps={(state, rowInfo, column) => {
                            return {
                              style: {
                                overflow: 'visible',
                              }
                            };
                          }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the answare was quite simple when finding the right props. I ended up searchin for `getTheadFilterTrProps` in the installation folder of react-table. Then I found that there were some more Props available.

I endend up adding

```
<React
    getTheadFilterThProps={(state, rowInfo, column) => {
      return {
        style: {
          overflow: 'visible',
        }
      };
    }}
```

Comment: this is not working for me. maybe api has changed now.